# What is the scope of public variable in different methods of a same class in Console C#

Tags: c#, variables, scope

I have a class named Data that is used to retrieve  a user's data

```
    class Data
    {
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public void getdata()
        {
            firstName = "ABC";
            lastName = "XYZ";
        }
        public static XDocument GetDataToXml()
        {
            var objget = new Data();
            objget.getdata();
            XDocument doc = new XDocument(
               new XElement("firstName ", objget.firstName),
               new XElement("lastName", objget.firstName));
            return doc;
        }
        public void display()
        {
            string fdata = firstName;  //i get "firstName"  value as null why????
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = new Data();
            obj.getdata();
            obj.display();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Why do I get null value when I call `disp()` ,Also I just want to access the values of `firstName` and `lastName` in the `GetDataToXml()` even there the `getData()` function gets called.What is the scope of this variable in spite me assigning it as public?

Comment: Your code doesn't call `disp`. Please post a complete example.

Comment: Sometimes debugger shows `null` until another line is executed.

Comment: Why is GetDataToXml defined as static? You create a Data object and call for getData but then you have to access that method with a Data. GetDataToXml() call which will again create a Data object and call getData.. i would suggest to get rid of that static modifier.

Comment: How did you concluded that `firstName` is `null`?

Comment: firstName is not null, fdata is until you step over that line of code during debug

Comment: @Dusan when I debugged the code

Comment: @DarrenYoung :pls see my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you a little i have redesigned your example :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Data();
        obj.setData("First", "Last");
        obj.GetDataToXml();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Data
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public void setData(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    public XDocument GetDataToXml()
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
           new XElement("FirstName ", FirstName),
           new XElement("LastName", LastName));
        return doc;
    }
}
```

Put a Breakpoint inside the GetDataToXML method and check both FirstName and LastName values.

Comment: I confused with the get and set methods...so didnt go for it ,if i need toset the values within another method then how should i do??@Olaru Mircea

Comment: @TechBrkTru those two properties are public, so you can call obj.FirstName and obj.LastName. If you want to get them in a format FirstName + LastName then take another method wich will return a string containing the above concatenation.  I already defined a set method for those two value, in order to set them from any method, call setData, it's public and non static so it will behave normally.